# MATLAB SHARC ADSP-21369 BTC failure

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am implementimg a BTC from matlab to the SHARC ADSP-21369 EZ-Kit to edit parameters for a simple 3-band-EQ during the board's runtime.

I have a class in MatLAB including the methods for accessing, writing and reading the BTC and i have initialized the channels in VisualDSP++ like shown in the getting started example.

My problem is as follows:

I transmit filter coefficients for a biquad filter, so the numerator-coefficients  are  3x1 cell array, and the denominator-coeffs are a 2x1 cell array

If i try to send these values through the BTC, the BTC memory window shows me that only one single coefficient of the array is edited, the others get 0. A very interesting point is, that in the 3x1 cell array the 2nd coefficient is edited, the first and the third get zero.

I need to present this work on Monday, so quick solutions are appreciated.

The function code is below.

```
    classdef accessBTC < handle



properties

    numChannels = [];

    isInitialized = 0; %Logical 0 or 1 to indicate if the class is instantiated to connect to the VisualDSP session

end



properties(SetAccess = private)

    channelList = {}; % Array of channel objects

end



methods



    function initialize(obj)

        a = actxserver('VisualDSP.ADspApplication');

        btcPlugin      = a.PluginList.invoke('Item','BtcManager');

        btcManager     = btcPlugin.Open;

        btcChannelList = btcManager.ChannelList(int16(0));       % Get the channel list in processor #0 (always INT16)

        obj.numChannels = btcChannelList.Count;

        disp(['Total Number of Channels: ', num2str(obj.numChannels)]);

        % Create the BTC Channel interfaces

        for i = 1: obj.numChannels

            obj.channelList{i} = btcChannelList.invoke('Item',int32(i-1));

        end

        obj.isInitialized = 1;

       % S=saveobj(obj);

   end % End of Method: INITIALIZE



    function outVal = read(obj,channelNum,width)

        % Default width is 32; other possible values: 16, 8

        % Channel num starts frm 0

        if nargin ==2

            width = 32;

        end

        widthStr = ['btcWidth',num2str(width)];

        btcChan = obj.channelList{channelNum};

        out_val = btcChan.Read(widthStr);

        outVal = cell2mat(out_val);

    end % End of Method: READ



    function write(obj, channelNum, val)

        % input val needs to be a scalar or a vector of int32 or in16 or

        % int8 values

        % Channel num starts frm 0

        if nargin ~=3

            error('WRITE method for accessBTC object needs 2 inputs.')

        end



        btcChan = obj.channelList{channelNum+1};

        btcChan.Write('btcWidth32',num2cell(val));

    end %End of Method: WRITE



    function reset(obj)

        obj.numChannels = [];

        obj.isInitialized = 0;

        obj.channelList = [];

    end %End of Method: RESET



end
```

so if i sending for example these single arrays

```
    num_1 = [1.324; -1.45; 0.83]
    den_1 = [-1.45; 0.74]
```

i am getting in my BTC memory window as floating point

```
    num_1 = [0.0000000; -1.45; 0.0000000]
    den_1 = [-1.45; 0.0000000]
```

has anybody an idea how to fix this?

i will add some pictures now, that you can cisualize my problem:

[matlab-debug](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gse023pi8156bx0/matlab.jpg)
[vdsp-debug](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o34tp9py5dr6b8i/vdsp.jpg)

thanks a lot and best regards,

markus

Comment: Can you post your main script which calls this, and a proper example of how it does not work?

Comment: do you mean my visualDSP++ main or my matlab gui?

in my matlab gui the function write is called like this:

        btc.write(0,num_1);
        btc.write(1,den_1);

num_1 is a single 3x1 num-array, den_1 is a single 2x1 num-array...

Comment: Im not an expert on this but does `function write(obj, channelNum, val)` not require 3 arguments?

Comment: no, because the classes and handle-classes in matlab work like this, this only means that you need an active object or something... i will now attach 2 screenshots ob my debugging that you can visualize my problem... thanks ;)